# Eilenberg-Maclane spectrum and $E_{\infty}$-algebra structure on singular cochain complex

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, steenrod-algebra

I'm trying to understand how the $E_{\infty}$-algebra structure on the singular cochain complex $C^{\bullet}(X)$ of a topological space $X$, in at least somewhat down-to-earth terms. (I'm coming at this from Lurie's notes on Steenrod-algebras, but maybe this is the wrong order of approaching things...)

What I already know is that the Eilenberg-Maclane spectrum is in fact a ring spectrum (in Switzer's sense) and I think that this should give (via Brown representability) the product structure on the cohomology ring of $X$.

I also know that it is possible to show this directly (Smirnov: On the cochain complex of topological spaces [1](http://dx.doi.org/10.1070/SM1982v043n01ABEH002437)), but it doesn't seem like Smirnov is using the Eilenberg-Maclane spectrum anywhere (and it feels weird to just ignore it).

It feels like there should be a reference on it at some place, but so far, I couldn't find it.

Comment: Are you looking for what's in [McClure-Smith](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0106024)? There is also [Berger-Fresse](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0109158) and the more recent [paper](https://export.arxiv.org/abs/1808.00854) by Medina-Mardones.

Comment: I found the McClure-Smith article, but I'm not sure how to put the Eilenberg-Maclane spectrum in this context (I only skimmed it briefly though).

Comment: You don't need E-ML spectra to construct the E-Infinity structure. It is something very combinatorial, like the cup product. You can find formulas in the aforementioned references.